# Domain issues on WHM

Tags: web, hosting, whm

OK so I'm trying add a clients account to my whm and for some reason it won't point to my nameservers. I've already just had them buy a hosting plan with hostgator but for future clients I would like to have this problem solved. shouldn't I be able to change their NS to my nameservers?

Comment: you need to point the "domain" nameservers to your server. Where are those domains are? Goddaddy?

Comment: thanks Celik .. the domain was purchased thru hostgator and only had the generic ns1 ns2 and when I tried to switch to my server I continued to get an error message to try again  later.. I think this was caused by the client not confirming their email now that I think about it.

Comment: One other question for you if that's OK. do I need to set up the DNS manually for each account I add to whm or do I just leave it as is?

Comment: Hmm that could be it. Check out this page if you haven't http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/dns-name-servers/how-to-point-my-domain-to-hostgator-when-using-dns-elsewhere

Comment: you can just also point the A record to your hosting ip to resolve the domain.

Comment: thanks for your help! I'll try this out with my next client! truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

There is an option of adding child name servers in domain control panel.

First you need to add your server's primary name server as a child name servers to the client's domain control panel and provide the IP address of your primary name servers. Now try adding your name servers as a client's name servers. This will fix the issue.

**Example**

You have a domain abc.com for which you have configured nameservers ns1.abc.com and ns2.abc.com.

STEP 1

```
Login to clients domain panel and add child name servers to ns1.abc.com and ns2.abc.com and point the IP Address of server where ns1.abc.com and ns2.abc.com are resolving and save it.
```

STEP 2

```
Now go to the name servers section and change value of client's name server as ns1.abc.com and ns2.abc.com. You will see this time you will be able to add the name-servers without any issue.
```